# Even odd words can be oddly even

Tags: word, wordplay, anagram

<sup><sup>This is an entry to the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #25](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/fortnightly-topic-challenge-25-wordplay): [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay).</sup></sup>

---

**How it works**
You are given 3 clues, ODD, EVEN and FULL.  The answer to each clue is a single word.  The ODD and EVEN words are anagrams using the ODD and EVEN letters of the FULL word.

*Example:*

> FULL - Rearranged letters
>   ODD - Hindu goddess
>   EVEN - Persistent shew

*Answer:*

> FULL - ANAGRAM
>   ODD - MARA (a, a, r, m)
>   EVEN - NAG (n, g, a)

Make sense?  Good.

**Now it's your turn**
1.

> FULL: Major revolution
>   ODD: Surprise attacks
>   EVEN: Missing light

2.

> FULL: Keeping obedience
>   ODD: Sent away
>   EVEN: Popping ears

3.

> FULL: Single plane
>   ODD: Pocket fuzz
>   EVEN: Toothy turner

4.

> FULL: Ruler measure
>   ODD: Carangid fish
>   EVEN: Fork bit

Comment: is each one always a single word?

Comment: This for the fortnightly challenge?

Comment: @yitzih Yes, the answer to each clue is a single word.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Indeed.  I've edited that in.

Comment: Cool puzzle concept. I'm a fan!

Comment: Did you mean `RAMA` rather than *MARA* in your example?

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps [Nope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mara_%28Hindu_goddess%29), but RAMA could totally work as well, if he is referred to as a goddess by anyone.

Comment: Really nice puzzle! (+1) However one way you could improve: Maybe have a more definite answer? Maybe the first letters say something or the last letters. Might just be me, but I'm not a fan of list answers. However, this is a very good puzzle idea!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I was thinking about having something like that, but decided to have it stand on it's own.  For one, it helps gauge how the community likes it.  Also, now that it can be familiar, if it pops up in a future puzzle, there will not need to be lengthy explanation of how it works.  I would like to see more puzzles like this used in more complicated puzzles later, as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Full answers:

1. **[(from @GentlePurpleRain)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48441/30633)**

   > FULL: Major revolution: INDUSTRIAL
   >  ODD: Surprise attacks: IDSRA* → **RAIDS**
   >  EVEN: Missing light: NUTIL* → **UNLIT**
2. (with help from **@YowE3K** and OP)

   > FULL: Keeping obedience: **ENFORCER** ?  (verb/subject mismatch)
   >  ODD: Sent away: EFRE* → **FREE**
   >  EVEN: Popping ears: NOCR* → **CORN**
   >   <sub>if FULL is "Enforcing", which makes sense, even is "CORN" which also makes sense, and odd "FEIGN" ...</sub>
3. > FULL: Single plane: **TRIANGLE**, I think?  (3 points, defining a single plane)
   >  ODD: Pocket fuzz: TINL* → **LINT**
   >  EVEN: Toothy turner: RAGE* → **GEAR**
4. > FULL: Ruler Measure: **DISTANCE**
   >  ODD: Carangid fish: DSAC* → **SCAD**
   >  EVEN: Fork bit: ITNE* → **TINE**

Comment: How is "Sent away" = feign? Doesn't feign mean faking something?

Comment: It doesn't, or I would have made that my answer.  I'm still trying to find something that works. :)

Comment: @Rubio - I have put up an "answer", but only so that you can edit it into yours without me having to put it as a comment without spoilers

Comment: @Rubio I'm unfamiliar with your answer for 2-full starting with an i, perhaps you meant to [start with an e](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enforcer)?

Comment: @DavidStarkey "Obedience keeper" might be better there

Comment: @Rubio You are correct, that is a much better clue.

Comment: If it's "enforcing", even would be "NOCN*", though, not "NOCR*"

Answer (score 6):

### Partial answer

1.

> FULL: Major revolution = **INDUSTRIAL** (Industrial revolution)
>  ODD: Surprise attacks = IDSRA* = **RAIDS**
>  EVEN: Missing light = NUTIL* = **UNLIT**

I had 3 and 4 before Rubio posted them, but was trying to get all 4 before posting...